# express global middleware not being called

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

As far as I can tell I'm configuring my global middleware function as described in the docs and in every forum post on the subject, but it is not being called.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  express 3.2.5.  In the log output I see the following:

```
Express server listening on port 9000
inside route
GET / 200 7ms - 2b
```

I expect to see "inside middleware", then "inside route".  Instead, I just see "inside route".

The code:

```
var express = require('express'), http=require('http'), path=require('path');

var app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('layout', 'layout');

app.use(require('express-ejs-layouts'));
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico')); 
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride())
app.use(express.cookieParser('kfiwknks'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
} else {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error (error);
    res.send (500, "Internal server error");
  });
}

app.use (function (req, res, next) {
  console.log ("inside middleware");
  next();
});

app.get ("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log ("inside route");
  res.send(200);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

This related post:

[Express 3 error middleware not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198129/express-3-error-middleware-not-being-called)

is specific to error handling middleware.  Mine is a vanilla middleware.

Comment: You need to `require("path")`

Comment: Thanks - path is required in the working example.  I added the require statements by hand in the post (and added path just now to the post).  If path weren't required, the code would simply blow up.

Comment: Put that middleware before you use app.router

Comment: Thank you - putting the middleware before app.router did the trick!

Comment: @user568109 please post that as an answer, not a comment so Jake can accept it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should put your middleware before you use `app.router`.

```
...
app.use (function (req, res, next) {
  console.log ("inside middleware");
  next();
});
...
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this did the trick!  My takeaway is that app.router has to be the last global middleware added before defining routes.

Comment: Thanks!! It helped me.

Comment: app.router appears to be deprecated in 4.x

Comment: in my case i call it after .listen method, i'm on 4.17.1 of express

Answer (score 14):

Updated answer for Express 4 users [from the Express 4 docs](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html). See example from docs below. Note that **`app.router` is deprecated** and no longer used. I also added a dummy route to make the ordering clear.

> You define error-handling middleware last, after other `app.use()` and routes calls

#### Example:

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello world');
})

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // logic
});
```