# Node.js - why aren't these modules working as I expect them to?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

The following code displays some behavior other than what I am expecting.

---

**What I expect:**

`GET /` --> display "Welcome" and close the connection

`POST /pages` --> increment/log the counter; display "in the POST function", and close the connection

`GET /someRandomPath`  --> increment/log the counter; display 404 message

---

**What I observe:**

`GET /` --> display "Welcome" and close the connection

`POST /pages` --> *NO increment/log of the counter;* display "in the POST function", and close the connection

`GET /someRandomPath`  --> increment/log the counter; display 404 message

---

**Code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var request_counter = 0;

var app = express()

    .use(express.basicAuth('test', 'test'))

    //serve the root (welcome)
    .get('/', function(req, resp, next) {
        resp.end('welcome');  
    })  

    //  count/log the requests
    .use(function(req, resp, next) {
        console.log('request# ' + (++request_counter));
        next();
    })

    //  serve "/pages"
    .post('/pages', function (req, resp, next) {
        console.log('in the POST function');
        resp.end('in the POST function');
    })

    //  serve 404
    .use(function (req, resp) {
        resp
            .status(404)
            .end('BB: not found')
        ;
    })
;

module.exports = app;
```

---

Why does the counter not increment/log when I call `POST /pages` ?

One thing I notice is that if I comment out the `//serve the root` section, I get the behavior I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you're supposed to define all of your middlewhere *before* you start defining routes, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691380/548304).

You're not explicitly using `app.use(app.router)`, but it's automatically called when [you use `app.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/548304).

Knowing this, I would most likely change your code to something similar to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var request_counter = 0;

var app = express()

app.use(express.basicAuth('test', 'test'))

//  count/log the requests for all except '/'
app.use(function(req, resp, next) {

    if (req.path != '/') {
        console.log('request# ' + (++request_counter));
    }

    next();
})

//serve the root (welcome)
app.get('/', function(req, resp, next) {
    resp.end('welcome');  
})  

//  serve "/pages"
app.post('/pages', function (req, resp, next) {
    console.log('in the POST function');
    resp.end('in the POST function');
})

//  serve 404 for all the rest
app.all('*', (function (req, resp) {
    resp
        .status(404)
        .end('BB: not found')
    ;
}))

app.listen(1234);
```

Comment: Aah, that makes sense!  Just to be clear, when you say "middleware", you mean the Connect stuff, like use()?? And the Express stuff like get() and post() are "non-middleware"??

Comment: @loneboat - yep; [middlewhere](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) generally uses `app.use` while the [application routes](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) (non-middlewhere) use `app.get`, `app.post` and `app.all`.